# Probability of a good run in a long sequence

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

In a sequence of many ($n$) Bernoulli experiments, what is the probability that there is a subsequence (consecutive experiments) in which there are $k$ successes and fewer than $k$ failures?

*Note 1*: The length of the subsequence can be anything in the range $[k, 2k-1]$, inclusive.

*Note 2*: The probabilities of overlapping sequences are not independent.

Comment: Of course assume $n>=k$.